# How to create a lookup table with noise in Python?

Tags: python, lookup-tables

Say I have a dictionary in Python `{1:'a', 100:'b', 1024:'c'}`

I want to build a function that can look for not only the exact value of the key, but also approximated values. For instance, the function can return `b` if the input is 99 or 101.

Could you suggest me some approaches?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzydict/0.0.1

Comment: Good solutions often depend on your concrete problem. If fuzzdict does not satisfy you can you give more concrete details? E.g. something like that is often used for strings (fuzzy searching) or pictures (near duplicate detection).

Comment: Hi, I will look to fuzzydict

Comment: @TiếuThủy Define "approximated values".

Answer (score 2):

If you have a finite range for the values of the keys that is known in advance something like this indexing with tuples

```
>>> d={(0,2):'a', (99,101):'b', (1023,1025):'c'}
```

To find the value of a key:

Find 1024.01:

```
>>> d={(0,2):'a', (99,101):'b', (1023,1025):'c'}
>>> next(v for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if k[0]<=1024.01<=k[1])
'c'
```

Find `1025.01`:

```
>>> next(v for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if k[0]<=1025.01<=k[1])
# throws an error because key is not found
```

Comment: Thanks. How could your solution work if the number is float, not integer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the speed advantage of a `dict`, you could bin your keys, e.g. by rounding them to the nearest multiple of 10:

```
>>> data = {1:'a', 100:'b', 1024:'c'}
>>> fuzzy = { ((k + 5) // 10) * 10:v for k,v in data.items() }
>>> fuzzy
{0: 'a', 100: 'b', 1020: 'c'}
```

When you want to check if a values is close to a key in `data`, you simply apply the same transformation:

```
>>> fuzzy.get(((98+5)//10)*10)
'b'
>>> fuzzy.get(((97+5)//10)*10)
'b'
>>> fuzzy.get(((100+5)//10)*10)
'b'
>>> fuzzy.get(((101+5)//10)*10)
'b'
>>> fuzzy.get(((1022+5)//10)*10)
'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own lookup function as follows:

```
import sys

def lookup(value, dict):
  nearest = sys.maxint
  result = ""

  for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    if abs(value - k) < nearest:
      nearest = abs(value - k)
      result = v

  return result

print lookup(101, {1:'a', 100:'b', 1024:'c'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for values within 2% range (configurable) with something like this:

```
data = {1:'a', 100:'b', 1024:'c'}

def get_approx(data, key):
    return [elem[1] for elem in data.iteritems() if elem[0]*0.98 <= key <= elem[0]*1.02]

get_approx(data, 99)  # outputs ['b']
```